# merge 2 different lists to dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to merge two lists with different lengths to dictionary. Pls help

```
listA = ['2','4','6','8','10','12','14','16','18','20','22','24','26','28']
listB = ['host1','host2','host3','host4']
```

expected output:

```
{
 host1: [2,10,18,26], 
 host2: [4,12,20,28], 
 host3: [6,14,22], 
 host4 : [8,16,24]
}
```

Comment: What is the basis of merging? How did `host1` get these numbers?

Comment: I am populating listsB based on number of available hosts, merging is based on length of listB, each elements in listB gets one or more values of listA & append

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to have a dictionary where every fourth element in `listA` is a member of `listB`. You can do this using python's list slicing, and using a generator function:

```
s = len(listB)
output = {listB[i]: listA[i::s] for i in range(s)}
```

This should be fairly straightforward. The fancy list slicing thing is `listA[i::s]`, which takes every `s`th element of `listA`, starting from the `i`th element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following dict constructor with a zip of the keys and a list of sliced sub-lists:

```
print(dict(zip(listB, [listA[i::len(listB)] for i in range(len(listB))])))
```

This outputs:

```
{'host1': ['2', '10', '18', '26'], 'host2': ['4', '12', '20', '28'], 'host3': ['6', '14', '22'], 'host4': ['8', '16', '24']}
```

Comment: This seems a lot more convoluted than using a simple dict comprehension, but is just as functional.